# Consider the function $f(x)=\tan(\frac{\pi x}{2})$ and $g(x)=\frac12\sec(\frac{\pi x}{2})$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I need an explanation on the following problem

Consider the function $$f(x)=\tan(\frac{\pi x}{2})$$ and $$g(x)=\frac12\sec(\frac{\pi x}{2})$$
on the interval $[-1,1]$:

a: Approximate the interval where $f<g$

b: Approximate the interval where $2f<2g$

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\tan(\frac{\pi x}{2})-\frac{1}{2}sec(\frac{\pi x}{2})=(\sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})-\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{\cos(\frac{\pi x}{2})})$.

$\cos(\frac{\pi x}{2})>0$ on $(-1,1)$.

Comment: my answer choices for a and b are $(1,\frac{2}{3}),(-1,\frac{1}{3}),(-\frac{1}{3},1),(-\frac{2}{3},1) $or none of those

Comment: For (a) I simplified the problem for you. Did you attempt to find out when $sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})>\frac{1}{2}$? (b) follows from (a) since positive real numbers don't affect inequalities.

Comment: Please explain to me why you subtracted the functions to simplify. Also, $\sin \frac{\pi x}{2} > \frac12$ between $\frac\pi 6$ and $\frac \pi 2$ if I am not mistaken.

Comment: We wish to find when $f<g$. This is equivalent to finding $f-g<0$. That's why I subtracted. After factoring we found that $\frac{1}{cos(\frac{\pi x}{2})}>0$ is positive on $(-1,1)$. To find when $f-g<0$ we must find the positive and negative regions of $\sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})-\frac{1}{2}$. For $x\in(\frac{1}{3},1)$ $\sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})-\frac{1}{2}$ is positive and for $x\in(-1,\frac{1}{3})$ it is negative.

Comment: So the answer should be $(-1,\frac{1}{3})$ since the product will be negative there. You wrote that $\sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})>\frac{1}{2}$ between $\frac{\pi}{6}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$. This is the case for $\sin(x)$ not $\sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})$